# How can I set Replica-set to switch automatically to another node when first node becomes down?

Tags: c#, mongodb, replicaset

I developed a sample application as below.

```
private static string connectionString = "mongodb://db1.db.com:27017,db2.db.com:27017,db3.db.com:27017,db4.db.com:27017,db5.db.com:27017/myTestDB?replicaSet=rpl&retryWrites=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000";
private static IMongoClient _mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
private static IMongoDatabase _dataBase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("myTestDB");
private static IMongoCollection<MyClass> _collection = _dataBase.GetCollection<MyClass>("myTestCollection");
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to start...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                var obj = new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "MyData", Email="asd@asd.com" };
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your email:");
                var email= Console.ReadLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    var endpoint = GetUrl(url);                
      Console.Write(_dataBase.Client.Cluster.ClusterId.Value.ToString());
                }            
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

I want to test my Replicaset. What should I do to change automatically primary node when my primary node goes down? 
Now when I stop my primary node (to test), I need to reset my application. I need to do this automatically.

Comment: Assuming you haven't configured your secondaries in such a way that they can't become a primary, all you have to do is shut down or disconnect your primary. Your MongoDB driver will automatically detect that the primary is down or no longer connected and will use the seed list defined in `connectionString` to communicate with the secondaries. There will be a small delay, but the secondaries will vote among themselves and elect a new primary. This is called "automatic failover". Go ahead and give it a shot!

Comment: @B.Fleming Thank you. But in this case I need to restart my application and I do not want to do that. I want application does not stop working. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: That doesn't require restarting your application server. You only need to shut down your primary DB node. If it's hosted on the same server as your application code, then don't shut down the server itself, just shut down the `mongod` process. No matter how you approach this, there will be some amount of actual downtime as a new primary is selected, though this downtime should be very, very minimal (almost undetectable). If you're really worried, look here for more in-depth instructions to minimize failover delay: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/